# Problemas com o getSupportActionBar() para botão (seta) Home e seta back ←

Tags: android, actionbar

Estou com problemas para dar a ação para o botão de home, estou conseguindo implementar sem problemas o botão de acordo com o código ↓

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Mas não sei como definir para qual *activity* ele deveria ir e como fazer ele "matar" a *activity* em que está.
O descrito até aqui é o indicado na imagem abaixo como **1**

[image]

Gostaria de ajuda também com o descrito como **2**, ele funciona para voltar na tela (*activity*) anterior, mas eu gostaria de defini-lo para voltar na tela principal, mas ainda não encontrei algum método para tratar este botão.

A ideia é que, o botão **1** volte para a *activity* anterior e o botão **2** volte para a *activity* principal "*Home*" e que sempre que volte para qualquer lugar a pagina fechada seja "matada", assim não consumindo processamento com o que não estaria sendo usado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para redefinir o que acontece quando você clica no botão **Back** da **Navigation Bar (2)**, você deve reescrever o seguinte método na sua activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    Intent mIntent = //Crie a intent para chamar a activity principal

    startActivity(mIntent);

    finish(); // Finaliza a Activity atual

    return;
}
```

Para definir o que acontece quando você clica no botão **Back** da **Action Bar (1)** você deve escrever o seguinte código na sua activity

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     switch (item.getItemId()) {

         case android.R.id.home:

             Intent mIntent = //Crie a intent para chamar a activity anterior

             startActivity(mIntent);

             finish(); // Finaliza a Activity atual

         break;

         default:break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

No caso de voltar para a activity anterior, em alguns casos você pode simplesmente chamar o método `finish()`, pois assim a activity atual será finalizada e a activity anterior a ela será chamada.

Comment: Como eu poderia definir uma ID para o botão superior (**1**)?  
Considerando que eu obtenho ele chamando a função:
 `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`  
E não tem nenhuma ID (pelo menos não visível)... Obrigado :)

Comment: @GuilhermeHS, Procure pelo método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` na sua activity que exibe a toolbar e veja qual é o arquivo de layout que é utilizado para definir o menu. Em seguida, acesse esse arquivo e veja qual é o id do botão de back

Comment: Não consegui encontrar este método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` tem algum lugar especifico que ela fica?

Comment: Ele fica na Activity que contém a toolbar. Se estiver meio complicado de achar, abra o arquivo da activity e aperte **Alt+7** para abrir o painel de *estrutra da classe* e em seguida clique no ícone do **az** na parte superior desse painel. Agora é só procurar pelo método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Então, esse que é o problema, não tem na minha _activity_ este método, [olha no print](http://imgur.com/aPJobJR) como tá minha _structure_, o que tá selecionado com o mouse é o que "invoca" o botão **1**

Comment: @GuilhermeHS, já entendi o que você fez, vc não está usando uma Toolbar, mas sim a Action Bar padrão do Android. Reeditei a resposta. basta trocar o **id.do.botao.back.da.toolbar** por **android.R.id.home**

Comment: Essa eu juro que é a ultima pergunta :/ ..... Quando eu uso o `finish();` ele não "mata" a _activity_ que eu estou, ele apenas vai para a outra e ela permanece ativa, tanto que, quando chega na tela principal se eu apertar o botão para voltar (**2**) ele vai começar a fechar de fato as telas que antes ele só trocou por outra, ou seja, ele apenas está trocando de tela, o `finish()` não está tendo o efeito de fechar propriamente dito, ele apenas está substituindo, se é que você me entende :/ (já tentei usar o `ActivityAtual.this.finish();` mas dá erro.

Answer (score 1):

De todas as formas acredito que esta seja a mais simples.

No metodo onCreate da Activity insira o seguinte codigo:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Agora vem o segredo, no arquivo **AndroidManifest** defina o pai da sua activity, ou seja para onde você quer que sua activity va quando precionado **"Action Bar (1)"**. 
Basta add a seguinte linha: **android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"**

Ex:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ProdutosActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_produtos"
        android:parentActivityName=".RankingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara seguinte, jeito fácil, cria um xml e nele você cria um toolbar(ao invés de Linear ou Relative Layout) mas vai precisar ser assim(`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`), pode ser bem simples:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:elevation="4dp">
```

Depois de criar você insere ele no xml que você quer que ele apareça, aquela onde deve aparecer o botão voltar:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/menu_back_button"
    />
```

Perceba que dei um id ao include, agora vá na activity onde o menu deve aparecer e insira o seguinte código, logo abaixo de onCreate:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Feito isso a barra deve funcionar.