# Abrindo uma activity e ao retornar salvando o estado da main

Tags: java, android, button, actionbar

Após muitas pesquisas me deparei com a seguinte situação:
Estou na minha **Main Activity** e gostaria de abrir outra **Activity**(passando parâmetros para **Activity2**[No caso a meditate]), após isto utilizar o botão back na toolbar e voltar para a Main.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problemas: Não estou conseguindo manter a instância da classe **main**, quando é feito o retorno pelo **ActionBar** é feita uma nova criação da **MainActivity**, assim perdendo o estado atual da main.

Nota1: Passagens de parâmetros estão ok, somente perdendo a instância da main.

```
 intent2 = new Intent(this, meditate.class);

public void passartextos(String tituloE, String textoE){
        intent2.putExtra("titulo", tituloE);
        intent2.putExtra("texto", textoE);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }
```

Na activity meditate foi feito as alterações no XML conforme um tópico do fórum BR StackOverFlow
[Problemas com o getSupportActionBar() para botão (seta) Home e seta back ←](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123632/problemas-com-o-getsupportactionbar-para-bot%C3%A3o-seta-home-e-seta-back-%E2%86%90/124728#124728?newreg=aa99145859b049b9b20575518e1b24e9)

Na clase **meditate** foi introduzido a linha que da supportactionbar

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

e no **AndroidManifest**

```
<activity android:name=".meditate"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

Em miúdos o problema se resume à:

**MainActivity** -> **Meditate**

**Meditate** -> ***New*** **MainActivity**

Comment: Como assim? Quando você volta está definindo outro onCreate?

Comment: O que você quer que aconteça quando clicar no botão back? Deve carregar alguma coisa na classe anterior? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Quando eu retorno é feito outro OnCreate e quando eu retornar eu só quero que dê finish na Activity Meditate.

Comment: No seu back nativo do dispositivo, quando você clica ao estar na Meditate o que acontece?

Comment: Volta para a Main da maneira que eu quero, sem executar o onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira o `onOptionsItemSelected` na sua classe `Meditate` usando `android.R.id.home` para finalizar a `Activity` atual. Veja:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // ação voltar do action bar home/up 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Então seu código deve ficar assim:

```
public class Meditate extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meditate);

        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // ação voltar do action bar home/up 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ack estou com problemas na implementação desse método, estou usando appcompatactivity. 
Conforme imagem abaixo:
http://imgur.com/a/aBLm4

Comment: @SayoanOliveira seu método tem que estar fora do onCreate

Comment: Mesmo fora do onCreate ele não reconhece a classe do MenuItem. http://imgur.com/a/ybZb4

Comment: @SayoanOliveira poste seu código inteiro, senão fica difícil saber qual o problema.

Comment: Tá na mão: http://pastebin.com/fLArYfFq

Comment: @SayoanOliveira você tem que importar o MenuItem. Veja : import android.view.MenuItem;

Comment: Ack tudo correto! Só estranhei porque o AS não deu sugestão de importação. MUITO OBRIGADO! Fiquei 4 horas parado para resolver esse problema.

Comment: @SayoanOliveira acontece! Boa sorte ai!!